# R - frequency count of number combination in vector beyond exact match

Tags: r, vector, combinations, frequency

Is there a way to compute how often a particular combination of numbers occurs in a vector?

Here is an example:

```
x <- 12348

y <- c(12348, 12348, 12348, 1234866, 1234586, 4444, 4444)
```

In the frequency count, I would like to include 1234866 and 1234586 as a match for 12348

So, in this case, the frequency of x in y should be 5

I tried different functions but was only able to get the frequency of exact matches.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What if you repeat numbers in x?

Comment: not sure I understand the question

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to use `stringdist`

```
library(stringdist)
sum(!stringdist(y, x, method = 'soundex') )
#[1] 5
```